# sys.objects in SQL Server shows all the objects or all object the current user can access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Does `sys.objects` show all the objects in the database, or all the objects in the database the current user has access to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) on `sys.objects`:

> Permissions
>
> The visibility of the metadata in catalog views is limited to securables that a user either owns or on which the user has been granted some permission. For more information, see [Metadata Visibility Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx).